# CSS, Salesforce, ExtJS, and the blues

Tags: css, extjs, salesforce, visualforce

I've been asked to demo some ExtJS UI enhancements to our current apps inside Salesforce.  This is just a proof of concept that ExtJS will work as a good UI replacement for the default UI that most of our VisualForce pages use.

Everything works great, that is, except a few odds and ends of the CSS.  There are lots of styles inside "...visual.force.com/sCSS/21.0/sprites/13013.../Theme3/default" that are messing with the ExtJS elements.  Specifically commmon.css and extended.css.  Here's an example:

*Extended.css*

```
body .x-date-middle, .x-date-left, .x-date-right {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

Is there an elegant way around this, or is ExtJS just not going to play well inside of Salesforce?

For example:  Is there a way that I can tell my VisualForce page to ignore commmon.css and extended.css?

Comment: We've been using extJS quite extensively and we couldn't get around this without resorting to modifications to extJS and/or templating. I'll offer a reward here, I am willing to know about this as well...

Comment: @mmix good to know I'm not the only one suffering here.  it is quite easy to override this stuff, but it really shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't speak to whatever Salesforce is doing, but if Ext's styles are being overridden (by any other CSS really) you have two choices: remove the offending CSS, or override the rules yourself.  Not much way around that in Ext 3.x.

In Ext 4 you'll be able to sandbox your Ext styles by customizing the global `Ext.baseCSSPrefix` config, which will effectively eliminate this issue going forward.

Comment: I could certainly give the ExtJS 4 beta a try.  Any links and/or examples of Ext.baseCSSPrefix in action are appreciated :) .  Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately, the policy forbids beta stuff for me, I am still interested to learn of a solution (if any). Btw, things get real ugly when SF itself joins the ext party. They actually use extJS 3.2.2 to render development mode utilities so we end up loading the extJS twice, and in different versions :)

Comment: +1 The ExtJS 4 beta does indeed solve this problem.  Don't you hate it when something that isn't really out yet could make your life easier?  Thanks for the hint.  I'm giving you the win as well, as this seems to be the only way to currently solve this problem.

Comment: As as side note, Beta 2 is out.  Tick tock.

Answer (score 7):

Do you need the standard Salesforce style sheets? If not, you can use the showHeader and standardStylesheets attributes to stop Salesforce from sending down the style sheets.

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false">
</apex:page>
```

Comment: This looks very promising.  I was enjoying some sunshine yesterday (rare in my area) so I'll have to give this a whirl on Monday.  I'll report back once I give it a shot.  Cheers!

Comment: +1 As this does get rid of the two offending stylesheets.  So thank you for that!  Unfortunately now my users don't see the header.  This will confuse them and they'll think they've left Salesforce.  Silly users.